# Dot Product of Matrices in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, performance-tuning, dot

How to efficiently solve a system of differential equations involving matrix dot product?

The example below is solved extremely fast when the array structure is flattened out. Is there a way to reach similar speed preserving the array structure?

```
x = 4; y = 2;
(ini = SparseArray[{1, 1, 1} -> 1., {x, 1, y}]) // MatrixForm
(a = SparseArray[
Flatten[Table[{x1, x2, y1, y2} -> N[ x1/(x2 y1), 2], {y2, y}, {y1,
    y}, {x2, x}, {x1, x}], 4], {x, x, y, y}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

[image]

Flatten

```
AbsoluteTiming[sol1 = NDSolve[
{
 f'[t] == Normal[ArrayFlatten[a].Flatten[f[t]]],
 f[0] == Normal[Flatten[ini]]
 }
,f,
{t, 0, 2}
];]
(*{0.007967, Null}*)
```

No Flatten

```
dodo[m1_, m2_, pos_] := TensorTranspose[Activate[TensorContract[Inactive[TensorProduct][m1,m2], pos]], {1,3, 2}];
AbsoluteTiming[sol2 = NDSolve[
{
f'[t] == Normal[dodo[a, f[t], {{2, 5}, {4, 7}}]],
 f[0] == Normal[ini]
}
,f,
{t, 0, 2}
];]
(*{0.195254, Null}*)
```

Both solutions are equal

```
Round[Flatten[f[1] /. sol1], 10^-5] == Round[Flatten[f[1] /. sol2], 10^-5]
(*True*)
```

Comment: Why couldn't you just re-partition the flattened solution afterwards?

Comment: The original problem is bigger and easier to read in the array form. Of course, re-partitioning would be plan B.

Comment: "The original problem is bigger and easier to read in the array form." - I don't doubt that. I'm just saying that this seems to be a situation where you have to choose between readability and efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

You can improve timings by giving `dodo` an argument restriction, so that it doesn't [`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate) too early:

```
Clear[dodo];
dodo[m1_, m2_List, pos_] := TensorTranspose[
    Activate[TensorContract[Inactive[TensorProduct][m1,m2],pos]],
    {1,3,2}
];
AbsoluteTiming[
    sol2 = NDSolve[
        {f'[t]==Normal[dodo[a,f[t],{{2,5},{4,7}}]],f[0]==Normal[ini]},
        f,
        {t,0,2}
    ];
]
```

> {0.029865, Null}

Compare to your version:

```
Clear[dodo];
dodo[m1_, m2_, pos_] := TensorTranspose[
    Activate[TensorContract[Inactive[TensorProduct][m1,m2],pos]],
    {1,3,2}
];
AbsoluteTiming[
    sol3 = NDSolve[
        {f'[t]==Normal[dodo1[a,f[t],{{2,5},{4,7}}]],f[0]==Normal[ini]},
        f,
        {t,0,2}
    ];
]

Round[Flatten[f[1]/.sol3],10^-5]==Round[Flatten[f[1]/.sol2],10^-5]
```

> {0.223253, Null}
>
> True

This is still quite a bit slower than working with flattened objects, though. It is possible to improve things further, but not enough to be competitive with flattened objects.

Comment: Thanks! That helps but with higher dimensions things get slow again.. I guess there is no way around Flatten. Just out of curiosity, how would you improve the array version?